# exercise 12.4 from "think python", the script doesnt get to the end

Tags: python

> What is the longest English word, that remains a valid English word, as you remove its
>   letters one at a time?
>
> Now, letters can be removed from either end, or the middle, but you can’t rearrange any
>   of the letters. Every time you drop a letter, you wind up with another English word. If
>   you do that, you’re eventually going to wind up with one letter and that too is going
>   to be an English word—one that’s found in the dictionary. I want to know what’s the
>   longest word and how many letters does it have?
>
> I’m going to give you a little modest example: Sprite. Ok? You start off with sprite,
>   you take a letter off, one from the interior of the word, take the r away, and we’re left
>   with the word spite, then we take the e off the end, we’re left with spit, we take the s off,
>   we’re left with pit, it, and I.

I wrote it by defining two functions:

- reduced - for a given word returning all the reduced words that are
  real words. if the word is "a" or "i" that means the word is the
  minimum length word so it returns `True`. if the word does not have any
  real reducible words it returns `False`.
- create - for a given word (it actually gets a one word string), returns `True` if the word is reducible till it gets to "a" or "i"

```
def reduced(words):
 ''' creating a list of reduced words True  : 'a' or 'i' False : no reduced words'''
    words = list()
    if word == 'a' or word == 'i':
        return True
    for letter in range(len(word)):
        reduced_word = word[:letter] + word[letter+1:]
        if reduced_word in world_list:
            words.append(reduced_word)
    if len(words) == 0:
        return False
    return words

def create(root):
    '''
   getting a list type!
   return True : root reducable till 0
   return False: else'''
    if root == True:
        return True
    elif root == False:
        return False
    else:
        for word in root:
            word = reduced(word)
            return create(word)

fin = open("words.txt")
world_list = list() #world list
reducable_words = list() #list of reducable words
longest = "" # the longest reducable word
# Creating world_list
for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    world_list.append(word)
# Creating tuples list
for word in world_list:
    if (create([word])) == True:
        reducable_words.append(word)

print(reducable_words)
```

The problem is, the script never gets to the last line, there is a problem with the second `for` loop. The `world_list` is correctly appended, so I can't see why this isn't working.

Comment: Check         for word in root:
            word = reduced(word)
            return create(word)
You have the return sentence indented inside the for loop

Comment: @Luis
I tried to fix it by doing this - http://pastebin.com/gGVHtC0m
But I cannot really figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your create() function seems of no value, I suggest tossing it altogether and focusing on your reduced() function which is very close.  I've made some small changes to it: world_list -> word_list; instead of True or False, it returns an empty or non-empty list; it only returns non-empty if a complete reduction can be found (but ignores multiple possible reductions.)

```
def reduced(word):
    ''' returns a list of reduced words or an empty list if no reduced words '''

    if word == 'a' or word == 'i':
        return list(word)

    words = list()

    for letter in range(len(word)):
        reduced_word = word[:letter] + word[letter + 1:]
        if reduced_word in word_list:
            words = reduced(reduced_word)
            if words:
                return [word] + words
    return words
```

Using this slight rework of reduce(), you should be able to finish off the remainder of your program.

('daunt', '->', ['daunt', 'aunt', 'ant', 'at', 'a'])